# Play Movie On Boot

Tags: cron, startup, vlc

I'm wanting to automate a cinema with Linux.  I would like to Play an MP4 on repeat directly after boot.  I currently I have a solution with Windows using a batch file that runs on startup and issues a VLC command.  Windows is obviously very problematic, but when it does work it works well.

- Movie Covers Entire Screen
- Movie Starts on Boot
- Computer Reboots Daily

Would Ubuntu be a good alternative to Windows for this application and what are the best mechanisms to ensure everything gets going on Boot, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a single-purpose device? If so, there are kiosk and Ubuntu Core options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in startup applications.

```
#!/bin/bash
vlc [name of movie]
```

Or if you want to play and exit

```
cvlc --play-and-exit [name of movie]
```

Comment: Might be cool to expand on this and have it look in a directory, start the oldest not seen movie available. It should be possible to find the "time until end" timestamp and if less than say 30 seconds or a minute the movie is seen :)

Comment: How would you know  the not seen movies? @Rinzwind

Comment: Those have no timestamp. vlc has somewhere stored where a movie is so it can resume where you left off. But we let TS find out how ;=)